# The file copying algorithm for Python is not working

Tags: python, copy

A code was written to do the following:
There is a folder (old_dir) with contains files of same type. The files have different sizes. In program we have to specify the desired size in MB (for example, 10 MB). Upon execution the program copies random files into the new specified folder (new_dir) until the size of new_dir becomes equal or greater than the desired size (abovementioned example of 10 MB).

The code in Python is as following:

```
import os, random, shutil

old_dir = "E:\\Desktop\\607" 
new_dir = "E:\\Desktop\\new" 
size = 10 * 1024 * 1024 
file_list = os.listdir(old_dir) 

while sum(os.path.getsize(f) for f in os.listdir(new_dir)) < size:
    file = file_list.pop(random.randint(0, len(file_list)))
    shutil.copy(old_dir + file, new_dir + file)
```

Folder "607" contains .jpg files with simple names 001, 002... (135 in total with a total size of 50 MB)

Upon execution it returns the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Desktop\111.py", line 10, in <module>
    shutil.copy(old_dir + file, new_dir + file)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\shutil.py", line 119, in copy
    copyfile(src, dst)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\shutil.py", line 82, in copyfile
    with open(src, 'rb') as fsrc:
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'E:\\Desktop\\607006.jpg'
```

Could you please help in pointing out the mistake?

Comment: did you just miss a backslash between the folder name and the filename?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a backslash.

```
import os
...
shutil.copy(os.path.join(old_dir, file), os.path.join(new_dir, file))
```

Comment: Thank you very much for pointing that out! But now the other problem persists: the program copies only one file into the new folder and returns an error "Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Desktop\111.py", line 8, in <module>
    while sum(os.path.getsize(f) for f in os.listdir(new_dir)) < size:
  File "E:\Desktop\111.py", line 8, in <genexpr>
    while sum(os.path.getsize(f) for f in os.listdir(new_dir)) < size:
  File "C:\Python27\lib\genericpath.py", line 57, in getsize
    return os.stat(filename).st_size
WindowsError: [Error 2] : '131.jpg'"

Comment: This is really hard to read in the comment without line breaks, but it complains that the file doesn't exist. Check what `os.listdir` returns, it probably misses the directory. Try `while sum(os.path.getsize(os.path.join(new_dir, f)) for f in os.listdir(new_dir)) < size`